# How to subset a list of shortest paths by a sequence of vertices?

Tags: r, igraph

Using this for loop, I have stored all the shortest paths between every node in the network "`original.graph`".

```
POI <- list()
for(i in seq_along(V(original.graph))){
    this.name <- V(original.graph)[[i]]
    sp <- shortest_paths(original.graph, from = this.name[1], to = V(original.graph), mode = "out")
    POI[[this.name$name]] <- sp$vpath
  }
```

Here is an example of the data:

```
> POI[[1]][1:5]
[[1]]
+ 1/44 vertex, named:
[1] V1

[[2]]
+ 2/44 vertices, named:
[1] V1 V2

[[3]]
+ 2/44 vertices, named:
[1] V1 V3

[[4]]
+ 2/44 vertices, named:
[1] V1  V3A

[[5]]
+ 2/44 vertices, named:
[1] V1 V4
```

So let's say that we want to subset all of the shortest paths that have "V1" "V4" in them, it would only select `POI[[1]][5]` in this case.

I am trying to subset all of the shortest paths that contain a given sequence. I have been trying to convert `POI[[i]]` to another object type, and it seems that using `as.data.frame.vector` has been successful. If someone could give me suggestions on how to approach this problem, or point me where to go from here I would be grateful.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want subset and how. Could you please provide a little data and a desired output in order to let us well see how the problem is and what might be the best way to solve it?

Comment: Yes for sure. Does what I added help?